# If $b$ is an odd composite number and $\dfrac{b^2 - 1}{\sigma(b^2) - b^2} = q$ is a prime number, what happens when $q = 2^{r + 1} - 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, perfect-numbers

(Note: An improved version of this question has been cross-posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235576).)

Let $\sigma(X)$ be the sum of the divisors of $X$.  For example, $\sigma(2) = 1 + 2 = 3$, and $\sigma(4) = 1 + 2 + 4 = 7$.

My question is:

> If $b$ is an odd composite and $\dfrac{b^2 - 1}{\sigma(b^2) - b^2} = q$ is a prime number, what happens when $q = 2^{r + 1} - 1$ (with $r \geq 1$)?

Without the restriction on $q = 2^{r + 1} - 1$ being prime, I only know that $M = {2^r}{b^2}$ must be an *even almost perfect number*.  (That is, it must satisfy $\sigma(M) = 2M - 1$.)

I guess my question can be rephrased as follows:

> > **(1)** If $b$ is an odd composite, how often is $\dfrac{b^2 - 1}{\sigma(b^2) - b^2} = q$ a prime number?
> >
> > **(2)** If $b$ is an odd composite, and $\dfrac{b^2 - 1}{\sigma(b^2) - b^2} = q$ is a prime number, how often is $q$ a Mersenne prime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that I can say is that if $b=3^k$ for $k>1$ then $q=2$.

Up to $10^8$ there are no other values of $b$ that make $q$ prime.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer to my **initial** question.

Let $I(x) = \sigma(x)/x$ be the *abundancy index* of $x$.

If $b$ is an odd composite and
$$\dfrac{b^2 - 1}{\sigma(b^2) - b^2} = \sigma(2^r) = 2^{r+1} - 1,$$
then I know that
$$b^2 - 1 = \sigma(2^r)\sigma(b^2) - {b^2}\left(2^{r+1} - 1\right)$$
so that
$$\sigma\left({2^r}{b^2}\right) = 2^{r+1}{b^2} - 1$$
whence $M = {2^r}{b^2}$ must be an *even almost perfect number* that is not a power of two.

If, in addition,
$$\sigma(2^r) = 2^{r+1} - 1 = q$$
is prime, then notice that we have
$$q + 1 = \sigma(q) = 2^{r+1}$$
so that we obtain
$$I(q) = \dfrac{\sigma(q)}{q} = \dfrac{2^{r+1}}{\sigma(2^r)} = \dfrac{2}{I(2^r)},$$
whence we get $I(2^r)I(q) = I({2^r}q) = 2$ (since $\gcd(2^r, q) = \gcd(2^r, \sigma(2^r)) = 1$).  Consequently, this means that $N = {2^r}{q}$ is an *even perfect number* (since $r \geq 1$).  By the Euclid-Euler characterization for even perfect numbers, $q = 2^{r+1} - 1$ must be a Mersenne prime, so that $r + 1$ must be prime.

Lastly, as an aside to [Giovanni Resta](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/312312)'s earlier answer, it is known (by work of [Antalan](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4882588)) that $3 \nmid b$.